# Check whether package can be loaded

Tags: module, julia

I'm creating a module A that can extend functions defined in module B (which means module A may have `using B` or `import B`). However I don't want to load module B unless the user already has add B to their system. An example code would be like so:

```
module A

struct MyStruct{T}; end

if(#= module B exists =#)
    import B: myFn

    function myfn(x::MyStruct)
        # ...
    end
end
```

An analogy of this would be the use of `#ifndef ... #define ... #endif` in C++ header files. Is there a way for me to check that user has added B, and is this a good pattern to use when building modules?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/MikeInnes/Requires.jl

Comment: This looks like what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check if a package is installed on the user's system is to peek through the Base method `Pkg.Installed` (read more about it here):

```
"moduleB" ∈ keys(Pkg.installed())
```

returns True if the requested "moduleB" is installed.

If you need to find out that a package is loaded then use `isdefined()`

```
(Main, :moduleB)
```

Hope that helps!